# Multiple Substrings in String

Tags: objective-c, image, loops, web, substring

I´m working on an app that displays 6 pictures from a website. These pictures change over time so I extracted the sourcecode of said website and managed to pull the first of the 6 pictures with this code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *deviantStringPopular;
deviantStringPopular = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://browse.deviantart.com/?order=24"]
                                         encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding
                                            error:&error];
NSString *popularContent;
NSRange popularURLRange1 = [deviantStringPopular rangeOfString:@"super_img=\""];
NSRange popularURLRange2 = [deviantStringPopular rangeOfString:@"\" super_w"];
int lengt = popularURLRange2.location - popularURLRange1.location -     popularURLRange1.length;
int location = popularURLRange1.location + popularURLRange1.length;
NSRange endRange;
endRange.location = location;
endRange.length = lengt;
popularContent = [deviantStringPopular substringWithRange:endRange];
NSLog(@"%@", popularContent);
```

The problem is, the other 5 images' URLs are between the same substrings as the first one.
So is it possible that the first image's  URL is ignored once the it´s loaded successfully and the second one loads and is stored under a different variable and so on?

thanks in advance

Comment: please mention the _relevant_ tags (such as cocoa)

Comment: Total side comment, but what is SO guidelines on discussions about copyrighted works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 6 URLs from the string and load them into different variables, you could try using a loop. With each iteration, after the substring is found and stored into a variable, make a range from the beginning of the string up to the end of the substring you found. You can use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` to erase the part of the string already searched so that the next time you search the string for the substring, it will find the next URL.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution may be to use [RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/), if you know how to use RegEx's.  Then each URL could just be a capture group.

Comment: Huh, haven´t heard of this yet, I´m pretty new to Objective C. Thanks for the advice, I´ll look into it